# TextChanged event of TextBox in GridView WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, mvvm

I am new to the MVVM pattern. I have a  form, that includes one `TextBox`, and one `DataGrid`. My `DataGrid` binding with an `ObservableCollection`. What I would like is to be able to have the search with `TextChanged` event of `TextBox` and show result in `DataGrid`.

I'm using a `TextBox` in the `GridView` and its in Model View-View Model. Basically, what I want to do is call a method every time the text in the box is edited. That is when the text is entered, the function will call. That is the text change event should work. But in Model View-View Model, what can I do? Please help me.Any idea....

Comment: I have done this, but to do it properly is a bigger task than you realise. Do you have anything done yet to start with?

Comment: In a text box, i know the working, but the text box in a grid view, i have no idea...please help

Comment: @user3192678: what means "GridView" in WPF context? Do you mean some ListView with GridView? If so, what is the items source for ListView and how it is related to the items source for DataGrid?

Comment: In ListView, i select the view as GridView.... ItemsSource= "{Binding Path= Stocks}"

Comment: You haven't answered about relationship between items sources. Show your XAML and view models, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trigger the function in the setter of the property that you bind to the textbox. You also have to set UpdateSourceTrigger of the binding to PropertyChanged in order to get it to trigger everytime you change the content of the textbox.

The function triggered in the setter should update the ObservableCollection, which will cause the DataGrid to update its content.

Se the code example below, code wont compile but shows the general idea.

xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

SubviewModel.cs:

```
public SubViewModel(ViewModel vm)
{
  _vm = vm;
}

private string _text;
private ViewModel _vm;

public string Text
{
  get 
  {
    return _text;
  }
  set
  {
    if (_text == value)
    {
      return;
    }

    _text = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Text");
    RefreshResult();
}

private void RefreshResult()
{
  // Do something with the _text and manipulate the _vm.Rows?
}
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<SubViewModel> _rows;
public ViewModel()
{
   //Initialize the sub view models
   _rows = new ObservableCollection<SubViewModel>();

   //Populate the list somehow
   foreach (var r in sourceOfRows)
   {
      _rows.Add(new SubViewModel(this));
   }
}

public ObservableCollection<SubViewModels> Rows
{
  get 
  {
    return _rows;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. Then you have to create a sub-view model that has a property for the text in the textbox and then you bind the GridView to a collection of this new view model. If you need a reference to the collection in this view  mode, you can include a reference to the top view model in the constructor for the sub view model or you could use some form of messageing, e.g use the Messenger clas in MVVM Light Toolkit.

Comment: Any Example for this?